# Activity data checkbox style

Tags: bug, design, preferences

Activity data checkbox style looks different on my iPad than other checkboxes on the [Preferences page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current):

> [image: style]

I’m using iOS Google Chrome 74.0.3729.155

Comment: The activity checkbox has `.s-btn`, while the others don't.

Comment: FWIW, the checkboxes on Firefox Nightly 69.0a1 on Arch Linux with Gnome 3.32.2 [aren’t affected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6KXJ.png).